# Why am i not able to update data in a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have inserted wrong values into the column product_id where invoice_no is 'Inv-3'. I decided to use update and set statement to modify the data in the column product_id but am unable to do so as it shows error "You have an error in your SQL syntax". Please kindly assist, thanks in advance!

```
CREATE TRIGGER `calc_gst`
BEFORE INSERT
ON `sales`
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.gst = new.gross_sales*0.07;
SET new.profit = new.gross_sales - new.cost_per_quantity;
CREATE TRIGGER `calc_profit`
BEFORE INSERT
ON `sales`
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.profit = new.gross_sales - new.cost_per_quantity;
INSERT INTO sales (customer_id, invoice_no, product_id, product_desc, quantity, cost_per_quantity, GST, gross_sales, timing)
VALUES('1', 'Inv-3','00002','Pocky - Strawberry', '2', '1.00', '0', '1.20', current_timestamp);
UPDATE sales
SET product_id = '00003'
WHERE invoice_no = 'Inv-3';
```

**Edit:**
I'm getting this error message,

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 'where invoice_no = 'Inv-3'"

**Edit 2:**

```
CREATE TABLE sales ( 
customer_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
invoice_no VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
product_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
product_desc VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
quantity INT(11) NOT NULL, 
cost_per_quantity FLOAT NOT NULL, 
gross_sales FLOAT, GST FLOAT, 
profit FLOAT, timing TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, product_id, invoice_no)); 

ALTER TABLE sales 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer_table (customer_id), 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product_table (product_id); 

ALTER TABLE sales 
ALTER COLUMN invoice_no VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the full error message here? thanks

Comment: Qns: What is the reason for the error?

Comment: Error message: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 'where invoice_no = 'Inv-3'"

Comment: IN multi statement stored programs (triggers,procedures,events,functions) you must wrap the statements in BEGIN...END and set delimiters. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html. Please fix your code so that we can see what you intended to be in the triggers and what you intended to be standalone.

Comment: Actually I just want to amend the data in the product_id column from Inv-3 to Inv-2 (last 3 rows of the code displayed above)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the update statement as a standalone statement which means the error is coming from code before the update. Please remove the superfluous code from the question and add the table definition for sales.

Comment: `create table sales(
customer_id int not null auto_increment,
invoice_no varchar(15) not null,
product_id varchar(10) not null,
product_desc varchar(50) not null,
quantity int(11) not null,
cost_per_quantity float not null,
gross_sales float,
GST float,
profit float,
timing timestamp not null,
primary key (customer_id, product_id, invoice_no));

alter table sales
add foreign key (customer_id)
references customer_table
(customer_id),
add foreign key (product_id)
references product_table
(product_id);
alter table sales alter column invoice_no varchar(15) no null;`